# how to store variable`s name in another variable

Tags: javascript, variables

i`m working on school project

how can i access the name of variable and store it to in another variable ex: y[i].

what to write in place of comment below in javascript code.

```js
var p = ["a","b","d"];

var q = ["d","b","c"];

var value = "d";

var x = [];
var y = [];


function testArrays(needle, arrays) {
  for (var i=0; i<arrays.length; i++) {
    x[i] = arrays[i].indexOf(value); 
   // y[i] = // store array`s name here
    
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + y;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p>Click the button to display the position of the element "Apple":</p>

<button onclick="testArrays(value, [p, q])">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not get the name of the variable...

Comment: What do you want `y[i]` to be?

Comment: i want to store the variables name because i want a list in which the element found

Comment: yes you can "sort of get the name of a variable". the "variable" has to be a property of an object. Eg.   var obj = {}; obj.Var1; obj.Var2 ... so on... then you can iterate the obj to get the "variable names"

Comment: @Mathletics i want the variables name here .

Comment: Consider using [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to insert elements in an array

Comment: @Ji_in_coding can you give me code please

Comment: no _literally_ what do you want the _actual value_ of `y[i]` to be? What should `console.log(y[i])` print? Maybe the other posters are getting it, but I fully do not understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: anybody please , help me?

Comment: @Mathletics i want y[i] to store the name of the array which is 'p' here

Comment: @MatiCicero, can you show me how by editing my code

Comment: @Mathletics , is there any way, i m waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you search for :  You have to construct a object with your arrays and pass trow all the arrays.

```js
var obj = {
  p:["a","b","d"],
  q: ["d","b","c"]
};
var value = "d";

var x = [];
var y = [];


function testArrays(needle, arrays) {
    for(key in arrays){
       x.push(arrays[key].indexOf(value));
       y.push(key); 
    }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + y;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p>Click the button to display the position of the element "Apple":</p>

<button onclick="testArrays(value, obj)">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm happy to have be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for what i was talking about. I'll give you the code. 
Again, to re-iterate my point, you cannot get the variable name. But if you must have the variable somehow, you can work around by putting all the variables you need access to in an object.

you will not get the variable name of the object, but you can access all the properties names of this object.

[Here is the codepen link to see the code running.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLXoNm)

html

```
<p id="test"><p>
```

js

```
var variableList = {};

variableList.var1 = 1;
variableList.var2 = -50;
variableList.var3 = [2,4];
variableList.var4 = "4";
variableList.var5 = 5.5;

var ele = document.getElementById("test");
for(var propertyName in variableList) {
   ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML + "<br>" + propertyName + " : " + variableList[propertyName];
}
```